# Store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

Depending on one variable I want to implement conditional rendering. Source code:

1. My variable

   ```
   let hideDeleteButton = false;
   ```
2. useEffect - to check value of the variable

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     if (projects?.length === 0 || useCases?.length === 0) {
       hideDeleteButton = false;
     } else {
        hideDeleteButton = true;
     }
   }, []);
   ```
3. Conditional rendering

   ```
   const DeleteButton = () =>
    hideDeleteButton ? (
      <Tooltip
        content={<TooltipContent title="The component belongs to either project or use case." />}
      >
        <span>
          <Button disabled onClick={handleDelete} color="error" classes={{ root: classes.button }}>
            {t('catalogPage.componentDetails.actionBar.deleteComponent')}
          </Button>
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
    ) : (
      <Button onClick={handleDelete} color="error" classes={{ root: classes.button }}>
        {t('catalogPage.componentDetails.actionBar.deleteComponent')}
      </Button>
    );

   return (
    <ActionBar>
      <DeleteButton />
    </ActionBar>
   );
   ```

And I got such kind of warning:

> Assignments to the 'hideDeleteButton' variable from inside React Hook
> useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over
> time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the
> '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly
> inside useEffect

What sould I do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any rendering related stuff, use a `state` instead of a `ref`. Changing a `ref` won't trigger a render.

`let hideDeleteButton = false;`

can be

`const [hideDeleteButton,setHideDeleteButton] = useState(false);`

and then in your `useEffect` :-

```
useEffect(() => {
  const hideDeleteButton = projects?.length === 0 || useCases?.length === 0)?false:true 
setHideDeleteButton(hideDeleteButton);
}, []);
```

Also important stuff - declaring simply `let` ,`var` or `const` variables isn't useful in React flow. In each render they will be reinitialized and lose their old values.
Here a `ref` is of no use since you want a conditional `render`. It would make sense where you don't want a value to participate in `render` flow but still want to remember that value between multiple `renders` for any other use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But IFAIK either const hideDeleteButton or using state, it does not make sense to make two variables with the same name.

Comment: That const hideDeleteButton is inside the scope of useEffect's callback and will not interfere with the state which is local to whole component. If you meant using some other variable name, that's really upto you but there is no logical problem here.